# MySQL + PHP: How to do search and show summary rather than entire result

Tags: php, mysql, search

was wondering how to do a search result using PHP + MySQL but not show all the data in the result but only a SUMMARY (lets say limited to 200 characters). And the summary would exactly contain the **keyword portion**. So -100 characters+keyword+100 characters might be how it would be shown.

Thanks!

Comment: With MySQL you could get the first 200 using LEFT() but to get -100 string +100 would be more complicated. Would there be any instances of the keyword existing more than once?

Comment: Yes.. it could be multiple keywords. But I would be okay with just showing summary around the FIRST keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are fine with taking the first instance of the keyword to use in your summary, you could break up the results of your query in PHP in a way similar to this:

```
    $sql = "SELECT data_field FROM your_table WHERE data_field LIKE '%".$keyword."%'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        $data = $row['data_field'];         
        $first_pos = strpos($data,$keyword);
        if ($first_pos !== false) {
                  $output = substr($data,max(0,$first_pos - 100),200 + strlen($keyword));
          echo $output;
        }
    }
```

Obviously you could do whatever suited your needs with `$output` once you had it.

Comment: Hey Thanks! But I am getting a parse error on your line with $output=substr($data....

Comment: Oops, sorry about that.  Messed up the brackets on copy/paste.  Try now.

Comment: No problem.  I made another quick edit to it that improves the length calculation for after the keyword.  Should be a bit better.

Comment: I used stripos instead for case-insensitive. One thing I did note is that if the keyword appears more than once in a paragraph, then it doesnt get shortened for some reason. It shows entire result.